# Is there a database of actions commonly associated with specific nouns?

Tags: data-request

Is there a publicly available dataset of particular nouns with the verbs that are often associated with them? For example: `{"apple": ["eating", "peeling", "cutting"]}` or something.

Comment: The magic word you're looking for is "collocation", and searching google for "apple collocation" (no quotes) may get you started. The main results seem to be from the Oxford dictionary, things like http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search1?word=apple (many other URLs with the same content). This isn't a great resource, since it doesn't even include "cut" (but does include "core", so that's something)

Comment: To expand on @BarryCarter's comment, you can use Bi-grams (N-grams of 2 words) with the first would being `apple` and the second word being inside a list of verbs. Here's a [visual example](http://goo.gl/ioDtQK), but none of the trailing words are verbs. Google N-grams can be downloaded or used via a python API, to name just 2 methods of accessing the data.